# User name history

Tags: discussion, users, account

It's a minor thing, but I'm wondering if there's any way to see what previous names a person has used.

I know that [this guy](https://serverfault.com/users/9140/pauska) previously used what I assume is [his real name](https://serverfault.com/users/9140/erik-p-skaalerud), and I think that before *that* he used the short name.  I notice and tend to check questions and answers of people near me in reputation, but I get confused when they change their account name.  So I was wondering if there's any way to see what other names a person has used.

Comment: Why do you need to know when you can see the list of questions the asked, answers they provided, and recent comments?  Maybe he didn't want you to know his name.

Comment: I don't _need_ to, but I find it easier in some cases to find things by who said them.  There's also a bit of cognitive dissonance when I see a comment or answer that I'm *sure* was said by someone else, and it would help alleviate that if I could find out "oh, yeah, that person did post w/ another name before."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over on MSO this has been discussed, but nothing has been done. Perhaps it's time to resurrect the thread.

[Keep short history of user display names](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28924/keep-short-history-of-user-display-names)